# logstash multiline codec with java stack trace

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse a log file with grok. the configuration I use allows me to parse a single lined event but not if multilined (with java stack trace).

```js
#what i get on KIBANA for a single line:
{
  "_index": "logstash-2015.02.05",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "mluzA57TnCpH-XBRbeg",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": " -  2014-01-14 11:09:35,962 [main] INFO  (api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker)   user.country=US",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-02-05T09:38:21.310Z",
    "path": "/root/test2.log",
    "time": "2014-01-14 11:09:35,962",
    "main": "main",
    "loglevel": "INFO",
    "class": "api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker",
    "mydata": "  user.country=US"
  },
  "sort": [
    1423129101310,
    1423129101310
  ]
}

#what i get for a multiline with Stack trace:
  {
  "_index": "logstash-2015.02.05",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "9G6LsSO-aSpsas_jOw",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:20)",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-02-05T09:38:21.380Z",
    "path": "/root/test2.log",
    "tags": [
      "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1423129101380,
    1423129101380
  ]
}
```

```html
input {
  file {
    path => "/root/test2.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^ -  %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}

filter {
 grok {
    match => [ "message", " -%{SPACE}%{SPACE}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{WORD:main}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{SPACE}\(%{JAVACLASS:class}\) %{GREEDYDATA:mydata} %{JAVASTACKTRACEPART}"]
  }
    date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "194.3.227.23"
  }
 # stdout { codec => rubydebug}
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong on my configuration file? Thanks. 
here's a sample of my log file:
 -  2014-01-14 11:09:36,447 [main] INFO  (support.context.ContextFactory) Creating default context
 -  2014-01-14 11:09:38,623 [main] ERROR (support.context.ContextFactory) Error getting connection to database jdbc:oracle:thin:@HAL9000:1521:DEVPRINT, with user cisuser and driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28001: the password has expired
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:131)
**

*> EDIT: here's the latest configuration i'm using

> https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9afe80ad604f9a3d3c00#file-output-L1*

**

Comment: You're not suffering from a grok problem, but a multiline problem.  Note that your second event should have been combined with the first event.  That said, the cause doesn't jump out at me.

Comment: I know it's a multiline issue that i don't know how to solve i tried many patterns along with it. but i don't get the result i'm expecting it's whether all   log lines are combined together in a single event or multiline parsefailure. I need to combine an event with its stacktrace.

Comment: Are you able to change the log format/add an improved format of logs? If yes, you could either switch to JSON or use online-appenders such as GELF or log4j/SocketAppender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First point, when repeating testing with the file input, be sure to use **sincedb_path => "/dev/null"** to be sure to read from the beginning of the file.

About multiline, there must be something wrong either with your question content or your multiline pattern because none of the event have the **multiline** tag that is added by the multiline codec or filter when aggregating the lines.
Your **message** field should contains all lines separated by line feed characters **\n** (\r\n in my case being on windows). Here is the expected output from your input configuration

```
{
"@timestamp" => "2015-02-10T11:03:33.298Z",
   "message" => " -  2014-01-14 11:09:35,962 [main] INFO  (api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker)   user.country=US\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:20\r",
  "@version" => "1",
      "tags" => [
    [0] "multiline"
],
      "host" => "localhost",
      "path" => "/root/test.file"
}
```

About grok, as you want to match a multiline string you should use a pattern like this.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => {"message" => [
      "(?m)^ -%{SPACE}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{WORD:main}\] %   {LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}\(%{JAVACLASS:class}\) %{DATA:mydata}\n%{GREEDYDATA:stack}",
      "^ -%{SPACE}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{WORD:main}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}\(%{JAVACLASS:class}\) %{GREEDYDATA:mydata}"]
}
```

}
    }

**(?m)** prefix instruct the regex engine to do multiline matching.
And then you get an event like

```
{
"@timestamp" => "2015-02-10T10:47:20.078Z",
   "message" => " -  2014-01-14 11:09:35,962 [main] INFO  (api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker)   user.country=US\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:20\r",
  "@version" => "1",
      "tags" => [
    [0] "multiline"
],
      "host" => "localhost",
      "path" => "/root/test.file",
      "time" => "2014-01-14 11:09:35,962",
      "main" => "main",
  "loglevel" => "INFO",
     "class" => "api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker",
    "mydata" => "  user.country=US\r",
     "stack" => "\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:20\r"
}
```

You can build and validate your multiline patterns with this online tool http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

A final warning, there is currently a bug in Logstash file input with multiline codec that mixup content from several files if you use a list or wildcard in path setting. The only workaroud is to use the **multiline filter**

HTH

EDIT: I was focusing on the multiline strings, you need to add a similar pattern for non single lines string

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Philippe. Here's the output when i use your pattern:
{       "message" => "2014-10-14 10:11:35,962 [main] INFO  (api.batch.ThreadPoolWorkFactory) some text here",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-02-10T12:26:11.179Z",
          "path" => "/root/trace.log",
          "tags" => [ [0] "_grokparsefailure"  ]}
{       "message" => "\tat some stack trace here",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-02-10T12:26:11.179Z",
          "path" => "/root/trace.log",
          "tags" => [ [0] "_grokparsefailure"  ]}

Comment: i used the filter multiline:
filter {
multiline{
        type => "multiline"
        pattern => "^\tat"
        what => "previous"
}

 grok {
    match => [ "message", "(?m)^ -%{SPACE}%{SPACE}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{WORD:main}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{SPACE}\(%{JAVACLASS:class}\) %{DATA:mydata}\n%{GREEDYDATA:stack}" ] }

    date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"]
 }
}

Comment: I still get the same error with the new pattern. each line is separated as a single event with grok_parsefailure.

Comment: i'm expecting something like this:
{
"@timestamp" => "2015-02-10T10:47:20.078Z",
   "message" => " -  2014-01-14 11:09:35,962 [main] INFO  (api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker)   user.country=US\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:20\r",
  "@version" => "1",
      "path" => "/root/test.file",
      "time" => "2014-01-14 11:09:35,962",
      "main" => "main",
  "loglevel" => "INFO",
     "class" => "api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker",
    "mydata" => "  user.country=US\r",
     "stack" => "\tat msg1
\tat msg2
\tat msg3
"
}

Comment: @sally can you please create a gist (https://gist.github.com/) with your config, an input file example and the expected output. Would be more accurate and readable

Comment: Hi, Philippe here's the github with all the details: (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9afe80ad604f9a3d3c00) I used back the input multiline codec because the multiline filter wasn't any close to the expected results.

Comment: @sally I commented on your gist

Comment: Hi Philippe, I answered you on github. here's the configuration file I use https://gist.github.com/saleeema/e480ae72fa431bee2a1f